# ADO.NET Sync Framework - Determining which records synced successfully/failed from PDA to Server

Tags: ado.net, windows-mobile, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, occasionallyconnected

I am using ADO.NET Sync Framework and on the client side (PDA running Windows Mobile 5 and .net cf 3.5 and SQL CE 3.5). Server side is using SQL Server 2005.

On server side manual queries have been written to determine which records are selected for insert/update/delete for each client as well as any conflicting records.

On PDA though, I can't seem to find a way to determine exactly which records were synced successfully and which failed. I can obtain the SyncStatistics but this just gives totals and I need actual row id's so that I can delete the successfully synced records off the PDA.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, have same problem..if you resolved it, please provide the solution here

Answer (score 0):

Are you not having a event handler for ClientApplyChangeFailed? You can use this for logging the failures.

Comment: Also, you will probably need ServerApplyChangeFailed - if you are worried about client changes not propagating to the server.